# Newsfeed textarea: How to pre-populate text, links, hashtags, mentions in the text

Tags: sharepoint-online, newsfeed

I want to pre-populate the Newsfeed textarea with hashtags, mentions and links using JavaScript:

[image]

Accesing the DOM element `$("#ms-microbloginputbox")` I can only add text. I tried researching the JS object `SP.UI.MicroFeed`, but I was not able.

Any hint?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ah well. I spent quite some time hacking the `SP.UI.MicroFeed` and it's not pretty since there are no public hooks you can easily use.

Here's some information that might help you:

The actual `Microfeed` can be found at `SP.UI.MicroFeed.SPMicroFeed.microfeed`. But this won't help you resolve the `overlays` (overlays are all enhanced informations in a post like people mentions, hashtags and urls).

The `overlays`are as far as I debugged build and managed by the `SP.UI.MicroFeed.AtMention` class.

**Update**

Found out how to trigger `typeAheadKeyUpHandler` but sadly it did not work as I expected..

```
for(var key in SP.UI.MicroFeed.SPMicroFeed.$O){
  SP.UI.MicroFeed.SPMicroFeed.$O[key].typeAheadKeyDownHandler({
     keyCode: 32,  //space / does not matter
  });
  SP.UI.MicroFeed.SPMicroFeed.$O[key].typeAheadKeyUpHandler({
     keyCode: 32,  //space / does not matter
  });
}
```

The function `setPostContentAndDataLinks` looks more promising.

**Update 2**

Found the piece which is used to paint the overlay. But sadly there are more fields that need to be populated.

If you fill the input manually you'll see how it's meant to look like. Add a User, Hashtag and Link and run the following script the current data is printed in the console.

```
var $feedInput = $("#ms-microbloginputbox"); 

//$feedInput.val('test @[User]');

//there are several instances of the AtMention class but in my case only the first one was important
//get the first AtMention implementation
var atMentionKey = Object.keys(SP.UI.MicroFeed.SPMicroFeed.$O)[0];

//ressources i found so far
console.log('Users', SP.UI.MicroFeed.SPMicroFeed.$O[atMentionKey ].$3D_1);
console.log('HashTags', SP.UI.MicroFeed.SPMicroFeed.$O[atMentionKey ].$2L_1);
console.log('Links', SP.UI.MicroFeed.SPMicroFeed.$O[atMentionKey ].$17_1);
//the second function will work when all ressources are populated
//SP.UI.MicroFeed.SPMicroFeed.$O[atMentionKey ].setPostContentAndDataLinks($feedInput[0]);
//SP.UI.MicroFeed.SPMicroFeed.$O[atMentionKey ].setElementHighlights($('#ms-microbloginputboxmentionhighlightdiv')[0]);
```

Comment: Many thanks for the hints.

As you said, I checked the behaviour of the Microfeed widget and saw the "extra" layers you mention for the enhanced content.

The code I was expecting for this would be something like this:

`// Invented code!!
var currentPost = SP.UI.MicroFeed.getCurrentPost();
var newLink = SP.UI.MicroFeed.Link("link text", "www.linkurl.com");
currentPost.appendLink(newLink);`

So you manage the post with an abstraction layer and don't worry about show or hide divs or whatever.

Comment: Actually you have to call the `typeAheadKeyUpHandler` to make it work. It will transform all `overlays`. Still trying to figure out how to call it..